# Redshift negatives of varchar(max)

Tags: amazon-redshift

So I've got sql server columns marked as nchar(1) for money symbols, and porting to redshift blows up because € is a 3 byte unicode character so needs char(3) in redshift (there technically is no nchar).  So I want to switch my etl solution to create all varchar columns as varchar(max).  In Redshift, does using varchar(max) for everything instead of varchar/varchar(100)/etc have any downsides?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does have downsides.

Strongly recommend that you **not** use `VARCHAR(MAX)` as the default column size. This requires more memory to be allocated during all phases of the query and will reduce them amount of work that can be done in memory without spilling to disk.

You can use `VARCHAR` sizes that are somewhat loose, e.g. 64 > 128 > 256 > 512, without incurring much of a performance penalty but only use `VARCHAR(MAX)` when you need it.

Comment: Ditto - don't do this.

UTF-8 byte length of strings is a function that should be known by your ETL.  If not you can set the varchar length to 4X the character length.